# An unusual for loop statement

Tags: c#, c, loops

In C and C# this snippet:

```
int ii;
for(ii=1;ii<5;ii++);
printf("ii = %d",ii);
```

prints out `ii = 5` whereas this snippet (notice the `<=`):

```
int ii;
for(ii=1;ii<=5;ii++);
printf("ii = %d",ii);
```

prints out `ii = 6`.

Can you explain what is going on here? How come the `for` loop ends with a semicolon?

Comment: Is it really i++ or is it ii++?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by: _for loop never ends up with semicolon_

Comment: this is an invalid statement for();

Comment: It is perfectly valid. for(;;); is also valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The body of your `for` loop is empty:

```
int ii;
for(ii=1;ii<5;ii++);
//                 ↑ body of the for loop
printf("ii = %d",ii);
```

The code sets `ii` to `1`, then increments `ii` until it's `5` without doing anything in the `for` loop body, and finally prints `ii`.

If you want to print the number 1 to 4 then you should place the `printf` call in the `for` loop body:

```
int ii;
for(ii=1;ii<5;ii++) {
    printf("ii = %d",ii);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++);
```

Iterates from 0 to 4 and with each iteration it does nothing. This nothing is the empty statement which is the semicolon.

This can make sense as e.g. here:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; printf ("%d", i++) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the for loops contains an empty statement (semicolon at the end), the value of `ii` is the value that causes the loop to exit.  So when `ii<5` is not true (because ii is 5) you see 5 output.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the increment portion of the loop declaration happens at the end of the loop, so the output is as expected - in the first example, the loop stops after ii becomes 5 (the loop body, which is empty, is executed with `ii` being 0 to 4).

The (empty) body of the second loop executes six times (from 0 to 5), and stops when ii becomes 6.

Answer (score 1):

With your codes, getting the output 6 is correct.  Here is the flow:
Your 'ii' is incremented to 5 and 6 respectively (to first and 2nd loop).  Because you are looping the for loop without 'the need' to execute the body

for(ii=1;ii<5;ii++); # the semicolon means you are looping it without the need to execute the body, which means it is looping without doing anything except incrementing the counter.

for (... )
{
 // body
}

without semicolo if you have 'the need' to execute the body.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon after the for, When expressing a for loop without {} it will execute code in a loop after the statement until it finds a ;  and in your case the for loop is not finding a statement to execute. Remove the semicolon after the for and your next line of code , the print statement will get executed.